# Why using _LatexSmallFractionConstant:=1 causes bad latex to be generated?

Tags: maple

The option `_LatexSmallFractionConstant:=1` is very useful in Maple, as it makes the fraction generated in latex looks natural. Here is an example

```
restart;
latex(1/2);
      1/2
```

Now using `_LatexSmallFractionConstant:=1`, the output becomes

```
restart;
_LatexSmallFractionConstant:=1:
latex(1/2);
         {\frac{1}{2}}
```

Which is the correct Latex.

But `_LatexSmallFractionConstant:=1` causes big problem in other places, like here

```
 mu:=1/((4*t+1)^(8/5)*(t-1)^(7/5));
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now see what happens when latex is generated with `_LatexSmallFractionConstant:=1` set

```
_LatexSmallFractionConstant:=1:
latex(simplify(mu))

 {1 \left( 4\,t+1 \right) ^{-{\frac{8}{5}}} \left( t-1 \right) ^{-{
     \frac{7}{5}}}}
```

Which is completely wrong. It renders as

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Removing `_LatexSmallFractionConstant:=1:` gives

```
restart;
mu:=1/((4*t+1)^(8/5)*(t-1)^(7/5));
latex(simplify(mu))

{\frac {1}{ \left( 4\,t+1 \right) ^{8/5} \left( t-1 \right) ^{7/5}}}
```

Which renders correctly.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Is there a way to correct the above, so I can still use `_LatexSmallFractionConstant:=1:` ? I need to use this option to make fractions appear in correct Latex, but I also do not want to obtain bad Latex in other places like the above.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Maple 2018.1 on windows.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug. You should report it. I'd link to where, but at the moment, it looks like both www.maplesoft.com and www.mapleprimes.com are down.